# YAML/Swagger bad indentation

Tags: yaml, swagger

Hi I'm working with swagger/yaml and I seem to be getting the error:

**bad indentation of a mapping entry
Jump to line 5**

The error starts at - invoke

Here's my code

```
assembly:
    execute:
      {{jwtCheck|indent(width=6,indentfirst=True)}}
      - invoke:
        target-url: {{ clusters.cluster1.ingress_url }}$(request.path)$(request.search)
        verb: keep
      - gatewayscript:
        title: check exit code
        source: >-
            let m = apim.getvariable('message.status.code');
            if (m > 299) {
              let r= apim.getvariable('message.status.reason');
              apim.error('AppError', m, r, r);
            }
```

Comment: Is the `{{jwtCheck|...}}` line supposed to be there, and if yes, is there supposed to be a colon (`:`) after it?

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like you're using Jinja2 but you don't mention this in the question. Swagger itself does not automatically process your input with a templating engine, so YAML would parse the `{{…}}` parts as mappings and that will lead to errors.

If you do preprocess the input with Jinja2, you need to set `indentfirst=False` because the Jinja2 expression is already indented 6 spaces and if you indent it again, the first line will be indented 12 spaces while the others will have 6 spaces.